# NullReferenceException in ItextSharp

Tags: itext

I got the following exception in itextsharp 5.0.6 library when I am trying to parse one PDF file

here is the link of that PDF File
https://backup.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c726b8f5a6673b56b6d

```
                try
                {
                    string s = null;
                    MessageBox.Show("Not-Protected");
                    PdfReader read = new PdfReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    //MessageBox.Show(read.NumberOfPages.ToString());
                    for (int i = 1; i <= read.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        s = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(read, i, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
                        MessageBox.Show(s);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                }

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentParser.ReadArray()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentParser.ReadPRObject()
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentParser.Parse(List`1 ls)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[] contentBytes, PdfDictionary resources)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent[E](Int32 pageNumber, E renderListener)
   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfReader reader, Int32 pageNumber, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also: iText 5.0.6 dates from February 4, 2011. That's almost 4 years ago. The current version is 5.5.4. Many bugs have been fixed in the last 4 years, especially in the PDF parsing packages. If the problem can not be reproduced in the current version, you are reporting a bug that has already been fixed (which is kind of pointless). So please show us a PDF that can be used to reproduce the problem in the current version if you don't want your question to be closed.

Comment: here is the link of PDF file which raise the above specified exception                                 https://backup.filesanywhere.com/fs/v.aspx?v=8c726b8f5a6673b56b6d

Comment: i've tested that PDF file with latest version of itextsharp 5.5.4 and stll i got the same exception...

Comment: I tried to check your PDF using Adobe Acrobat Preflight, but Preflight failed utterly... the PDF looks broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content stream of the first page of the PDF contains an array start bracket '[' inside the array operand of a **TJ** operator. This is not allowed as the array operand of a **TJ** operator may only contain strings and numbers.

Furthermore there is no matching array end bracket ']' inside that array operand, so the end bracket of the array operand itself closes this (illegal) inner array and the array operand does not have a closing bracket anymore. Thus, iText parses all the remaining content stream into the array and at the end of the content stream runs into the exception.

Adobe Reader is well known to ignore certain errors and try to fix others on the run. Knowing that there are no nested arrays allowed in page content descriptions, it seems to simply ignore the illegal opening bracket. This behavior of Adobe Reader is quite a nuisance because it allows defect PDF creation software to flourish.

PS: The line in question:

```
[(&)110($,"#'#"0'#.\(1\(2'0',#+345467839':'#.\(1;<"'0',#;345467839':'#.\(1!=.0',#\(345467839':'+.\(1\(2'0',#+7)(5)35(5467834':'+.\(1;<"0',#;7)(5)35(5467834)[(&)110($,"#'#"0'#.\(1\(2'0',#+345467839':'#.\(1;<"'0',#;345467839':'#.\(1!=.0',#\(345467839':'+.\(1\(2'0',#+7)(5)35(5467834':'+.\(1;<"0',#;7)(5)35(5467834)(':'*!>1;<"0',#;385467837)] TJ
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>^
```